# Null coalescing operator in React JS/ Typescript

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, typescript, null-check

We have the Null coalescing operator in `.NET` and we can use as below

```
string postal_code = address?.postal_code;
```

Same thing can we do in React JS?

What i found like we can do with && operator

in **address.ts** file

```
string postal_code = address && address.postal_code;
```

what i need like .net feature is possible in typescript with react JS, is that possible ?

something like:

```
string postal_code = address?.postal_code // I am getting the error in this line if I try to use like .NET
```

Comment: It wil be soon..https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a proposed feature in TypeScript, under the legendary [Issue #16](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16)

It won't be introduced into TypeScript until the ECMAScript spec for this feature is firm as there is a desire for the TypeScript implementation to follow that specification - so you'll get it early, but not massively early in this case.

It is referred to as any of the following:

- Null Propagation Operator
- Existential Operator
- Null Coalesce Operator

Comment: Any update on this? Looks like the issue is still locked. Also, are there any efficient workarounds for the time being?

Comment: The "null coalesce" operator is the [related-but-different](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) `??` operator. Also both of these proposals recently went to stage 2, so hopefully it will be implemented soon!

Answer (score 5):

**Update in 2020**: The nullish-coalescing operator mentioned below is now through the process and in ES2020, as is the [optional chaining operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) that lets you do:

```
let postal_code = address?.postal_code;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
```

With optional chaining, if `address` is `null` or `undefined`, `postal_code` will get `undefined` as its value. But if `address` is neither `null` nor `undefined`, `postal_code` will get the value of `address.postal_code`.

---

JavaScript doesn't have a null-coalescing operator (nor does TypeScript, which *mostly* limits itself to adding a type layer and adopting features that are reasonably far along the path to making it into JavaScript). There [is a proposal for a JavaScript `null`-coalescing operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing), but it's only at Stage 1 of [the process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/).

Using the `&&` idiom you've described is a fairly common approach:

```
let postal_code = address && address.postal_code;
```

If `address` is `null` (or any other falsy¹ value), `postal_code` will be that same value; otherwise, it will be whatever value `address.postal_code` was.

---

¹ The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false`.