# Overload `?` operator in javascript to handle null or undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to overload the `?` operator in Javascript to gracefully handle null or undefined.

An example use case is `const userAddress = user?.address`. `userAddress` is either some valid value or `null/undefined`.

If this is not possible in javascript, is it possible to overload the `?` operator in any one of the languages that compile to javascript (ex. typescript).

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining

Comment: You can use the `&&`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872267/null-coalescing-operator-in-react-js-typescript

Comment: Exists in Coffee. Not yet there in TS. You can use Lodash get for that purpose.

Comment: You cannot overload any operator in JavaScript. For that one specifically, "optional chaining" is coming to JavaScript soon so you can use [babel](https://dev.to/sammyisa/optional-chaining-may-be-coming-to-javascript--4ff0) to transpile. TypeScript itself is [waiting for a decision on the proposal from TC39](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16) before implementing it, since it doesn't want to stray away from JavaScript.